Creando un reproductor de música online, cuando le hago la prueba desde cualquier navegador no funciona el botón de reproducir
Estoy creando un reproductor de música online, y cuando hago la prueba del reproductor me funciona en el programa de edición de código pero cuando lo quiero visualizar en cualquier navegador no funciona el play.
Este es el código que estoy utilizando:


const audioElement = new Audio();
audioElement.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
audioElement.src = 'https://designjdy.com/proxy/vinonuevo/stream';

const playPauseBtn = document.getElementById('playPauseBtn');
const volumeControl = document.getElementById('volumeControl');
const statusElement = document.getElementById('status');
let isPlaying = false;

playPauseBtn.addEventListener('click', togglePlayPause);
//volumeControl.addEventListener('input', adjustVolume);

function togglePlayPause() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    audioElement.pause();
    playPauseBtn.innerHTML = '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M8 5v14l11-7z"/></svg>';
    statusElement.textContent = '';
  } else {
    audioElement.play().then(() => {
      playPauseBtn.innerHTML = '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M6 19h4V5H6v14zm8-14v14h4V5h-4z"/></svg>';
      statusElement.textContent = '';
    }).catch(e => {
      console.error('Error playing audio:', e);
      statusElement.textContent = 'Error: Unable to play audio';
    });
  }
  isPlaying = !isPlaying;
}
<button id="playPauseBtn">Reproducir</button>
<div id="volumeControl"><input /></div>
<div id="status"></div>




¿Y el html de ese código no lo puedes poner también en la pregunta?

Si claro es este...

No me deja enviar el html. Perdona soy nuevo en este foro

Pulsa sobre [edit] y agrega el html donde quieras

Lo he hecho y me da error. No me deja publicarlo :(

¿Y que error te da?  Si acaso pégalo en un https://pastebin.com/ y ya te lo pondré yo cuando me pases el enlace de pastebin creado

Ya lo he pegado donde me dijiste.

este es el enlace... https://pastebin.com/SbxQxbXi

¿Te fijaste si en consola da algún error? Por cierto, agrega el html a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica <>). Si te da error de que tu pregunta es mayormente código, pon el texto como tal, y se le dará formato a través de una edición. No olvides que tu ejemplo debe ser un [repro] (énfasis en mínimo).

la etiqueta html ya se la he puesto y me sal este error desde consola... Access to audio at 'https://designjdy.com/proxy/vinonuevo/stream' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Bueno, ya he visto el enlace, y quizás debería haberte dicho que pegues solo el html que afecta a ese código, pues lo que has hecho es pegar toda la página.  ¿Y que html afecta a ese código?  Pues el que aparece referenciado con los getElementById, y quizás alguno más, pero NO toda la página. Por eso no te deja pegarlo.  Igualmente, pegando toda esa página en https://jsfiddle.net/Lefh42ow/ me dice "song is undefined"

Si acaso bájate ese stream a local y mira de llamarlo desde allí, pues si te la pegas con CORS la cosa se complica y no se ayudarte, lo siento. Suerte!

Gracias. Lo he intentado todo y sigue sin funcionar. Pero nuevamente gracias por tu atención.

@jorgeluis convertí tu código a snippet para que sea más fácil de reproducir tu error y para que te sea más fácil de editar
